# Challenging Postgres sql searching in text array by any value from text array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, function, plpgsql

so here is my problem to make a query to work, it's extremelely challenging to make it, I was using `unnest`, searching using `@>`, nothing works.

I have a table in db that has `text[]` field, and I am passing `text[]` field to function that any of the values from it should return the row, or if I don't pass the value it should return all of them. For example:

table:

```
id (int)
names (text[])
```

data in db:

```
id   names
---------------------------------
1    { alex }
2    { tom, john }
3    { tom, alex }
4    { rocky, simon, leon, john }
```

how it should work?

- when I pass `{simon}` it should return only row `4`
- when I pass `{alex}` it should return rows `1` and `3`
- when I pass `{tom,leon}` it should return rows `2`, `3` and `4`
- when I pass null, it should return rows `1,2,3,4`
- any `in` parameter that matches any value from row, should return row

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_names
(
    _names TEXT[]
)
RETURNS JSONB
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT
        json_agg(t)
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                n.id,
                n.names
            FROM
                public.names n
            WHERE
               _names IS NULL 
               OR exists (select unnest(cast(_names as text[]))) = ANY (n.names)
        ) t);
END;
$BODY$;
```

I had no success on any of my queries getting errors like:

- operator does not exist: boolean = character varying
- ANY/ALL (array) does not support set arguments
- More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
- and more..

as you can see I was really trying to make it work, but to me it's super hard and I need some of your help.

Comment: What do you want to get if you pass `{tom,arthur}` i.e. where one parameter value does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator `&&` will do what you want

```
select *
from test
where names && array['tom', 'leon']
```

The above will return all rows where `names` contains at least one element from the right hand side.

To deal with a NULL parameter you can use a `NULL` check in your function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_names (_names TEXT[] default null )
  RETURNS JSONB
LANGUAGE sql
AS 
$BODY$
  SELECT jsonb_agg(t)
  FROM (
    SELECT n.id, n.names
    FROM public.test n
    WHERE _names is null 
      OR n.names && _names 
  ) t;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: @trinny: the `@>` will return what you described in your question.

Comment: i think 3rd condition `when I pass {tom,leon} it should return rows 2, 3 and 4` will not work. So it should be `&&` not `@>`.

Answer (score 0):

Write your function this way using `&&` operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_names (_names TEXT[] default null )
RETURNS JSONB
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    
    (SELECT
        json_agg(t)
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                id,
                names
            FROM
                public.test n
            WHERE
                case 
                when _names IS not NULL then names && _names 
                else 1=1
                end
        ) t);
END;
$BODY$;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3d5a7837f85db5deba4b2414e47a1e3e)